# Redo Firebase Database Read on onCancelled

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing an Android app and I'm currently trying to read data from my Firebase databese. I followed the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) on how to read. Now in the case when OnCancelled is called (meaning the Firebase read has failed) I check if the failure was because of internect connection so I can prompt the user to handle that.

So now my code consists of the following:

1. A static function in a class that checks for internet, show a dialog to the user, tries to reconnect every two seconds and then shows the dialog again if not connected. It keeps doing that until the internet is connected then it calls back a callback function to do actions after internet connects.
2. The firebase `ValueEventListener` with both `onDataChange` and `onCancelled`

Here're both codes:

### Connection

```
/**
* Defined in some separate file in a class called SharedStuff
* This function launches a child thread for checking internet connection. 
* It also shows a dialog for the user to reconnect
* Body of the function is irrelevant
*
* @param caller The caller activity. Needed to launch dialogs
* @param callback Actions to do when internet connects
* @param timeout A timeout period after which we will stop trying
*/
public static void isInternetAvailable(final Activity caller, final Callable<Void> callback, final int timeout);
```

### Firebase

```
/**
* Firebase stuff
* Inside my main activity file
*/
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mDB.getReference("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
    {
        if (databaseError.getCode() == DatabaseError.DISCONNECTED || databaseError.getCode() == DatabaseError.NETWORK_ERROR)
        {
            /**
            * Need to try call the internet connection function here with some callback!
            */
            SharedStuff.isInternetAvailable(MainActivity.this, new Callable<Void>()
            {
                @Override
                public Void call()
                {
                    // Need to fill this callback!
                    return null;
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "Reading database failed", databaseError.toException());
        }
    }
});
```

So now I'm stuck trying to fill this callback with suitable actions. Basically what I'd like it to do is try reading again until the read succeeds, or show the same internet dialog again if the it fails for the same reason (I know it's pretty hard for this to happen, but I have seen some really flickering network connections and would like to be on the safe side by handling this case).
So the methods I've considered/tried are the following:

#### 1- Force Data Changed event to happen

However, I couldn't find any API calls in the firebase documentation that would have this effect.

#### 2- Manually add `ValueEventListener` again

In this case I use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener` but then I try do connect it again inside onCancelled!
The code for this case would look like this:

```
/**
* Firebase stuff
*/
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mDB.getReference("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
    {
        if (databaseError.getCode() == DatabaseError.DISCONNECTED || databaseError.getCode() == DatabaseError.NETWORK_ERROR)
        {
            /**
            * Need to call the internet connection function here with some callback!
            */
            SharedStuff.isInternetAvailable(WelcomeActivity.this, new Callable<Void>()
            {
                @Override
                public Void call()
                {
                    mDB.getReference("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(Outer.this);
                    return null;
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "Reading database failed", databaseError.toException());
        }
    }
});
```

The problem in this case is that the keyword `this` would be for the `Callable` object not for the `ValueEventListener` and I'm not sure what to substitute the word `Outer` for to make `this` point to the Listener instead!

What can I do here to reconnect and reread? Whether it's Option 1 or 2 or something else entirely. I just would like to be able to do the following when `onCancelled` gets called: check internet connection, retry reading when connected, and keep doing this if the connection fails again (You could think of this as recursion)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[onCancelled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener.html#onCancelled(com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError)) is triggered:

> ... in the event that this listener either failed at the server, or is
>   removed as a result of the security and Firebase Database rules.

It doesn't get invoked if there is a network error.  When the client is unable to reach the Firebase server, it will internally retry the connection *and* any pending reads or writes.  You don't have to write any code to handle this situation.  In fact, you *can't* change this behavior.

Comment: But network error codes are listed here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseError as possible `DatabaseError`?

Comment: Just because you're given a DatabaseError, it doesn't mean that all of those circumstances are valid.  DatabaseError is a generalized exception used in many places.  Instead, you should use the description of `onCancelled` to determine what it does, which I linked to.

Comment: Thanks. I also just checked the last paragraph here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write which agrees with what you said (although it doesn't explicitly say it works with reads).

Comment: Yes, all operations will effectively resume.  Listeners will be reattached and will receive results as if nothing happened.